# Ajuda em Mysql para Retornar os Dias Indisponíveis para Marcação de Horários

Tags: mysql, mysqli, sql-select

Eu tenho 2 tabelas mysql que representam os dias indisponíveis para marcação de horários:

Tabela **holidays**:
id, day (date), name

Tabela **special_days**:
id, day (date), will_work(boolean)

Na querie eu preciso selecionar os dias indisponíveis que são os holidays, os special_days em que o will_work. 
Até aqui tudo bem, porém caso exista um special_day em que a data é igual ao de algum holiday e o will_work for true eu preciso retirar esta data da lista.

Até agora consegui apenas:

```
    SELECT day FROM holidays
    UNION SELECT day FROM special_days WHERE will_work = FALSE;
```

Mas não consegui retirar os holidays onde existe algum special_day com will_work é true e day igual;

Comment: Poste seu código onde você está com dificuldade, assim fica dificil lhe ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT day
FROM holidays
where day not in (SELECT day FROM special_days WHERE will_work = TRUE)
UNION
SELECT day
FROM special_days
WHERE will_work = FALSE;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu tudo certo agora !

Answer (score 0):

E se restringir a consulta fazendo um `subselect` para filtrar somente os dias:

```
 SELECT day 
   FROM holidays h 
  WHERE h,day in (SELECT day FROM special_days WHERE will_work = FALSE);
```